# XSL copy then replace attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

INPUT.xml

```
 <human gender="male" nationality="american">
    <property>blank</property>
 </human>
```

(desired) OUTPUT.xml

```
 <human gender="male" nationality="american">
    <property>blank</property>
 </human>
 <person gender="female" nationality="british">
    <property>blank</property>
 </person>
```

Hi guys, the above is my desired transform.
I have the following xsl so far:

```
 <xsl:template match="human">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <person>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </person>   
</xsl:template>
```

But how i go about replacing the attribute values
I tried using a xsl:choose but without luck

Comment: Your desired output document is not a well-formed XML document and I would recommend you either a) produce a document that has a single outermost element (with everything else inside) or b) do not name it `*.xml`. Also, please show a complete, minimal XSLT stylesheet. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet was close, it just lacks a template matching those nodes that are not matched by your other template, so they do not get picked up by the [built-in templates of XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

For the transformation of the attributes I chose to introduce modes, so that some templates only match in the second case where you want to change the attribute values.

The following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="human">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <person>
        <!-- mode is used to separate this case from the other where things are copied unchanged -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="other" />
    </person>   
</xsl:template>

<!-- templates for normal mode -->

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- templates for "other" mode -->

<xsl:template match="@gender" mode="other">
    <xsl:attribute name="gender">
        <xsl:if test=". = 'male'">female</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'female'">male</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@nationality" mode="other">
    <xsl:attribute name="nationality">
        <xsl:if test=". = 'american'">british</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test=". = 'british'">american</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="other">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input:

```
<human gender="male" nationality="american">
    <property>blank</property>
</human>
```

gives the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<human gender="male" nationality="american">
    <property>blank</property>
</human>
<person gender="female" nationality="british">
    <property>blank</property>
</person>
```

Comment: Please do not answer too early which potentially prevents askers to edit and improve their question. Your ouput is not quite right, one of the genders should be "female" and "british" should be in it.

Comment: Tks for the reply. Unfortunately i do have a use case of converting an american man to british lady....

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that. The first version just accounted for the obvious incompleteness of the original stylesheet. Sorry for that.